# Paginate Comments and Models in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, comments, paginator

I am trying to paginate comments section and cadmodels section...but nothing happened...Please tell me where i am wrong.

Here is a code for pagination..

```
   public function index()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();
        $user->load('cadmodels','comments.cadmodel')->paginate(5);

        $categories = Categories::all();
        return view('dashboard.index',['user'=>$user,'categories'=>$categories]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add {{ $whatever->links() }} , on the view where you are displaying the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();
    $user->load('cadmodels','comments.cadmodel');

    $categories = Categories::all();
    return view('dashboard.index',['user'=>$user->paginate(5),'categories'=>$categories]);
}
```